# Add legend tooltip in plotly output

Tags: r, ggplot2, tooltip, plotly

I have the following plotly output:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
df <- data.frame(V1=gl(6,20), V2=gl(40,3))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=V1, fill=V2)) + geom_bar(color="white")
fixed<-ggplotly(p)

for (i in 1:length(levels(df$V2))){
  fixed$x$data[[i]]$text[length(fixed$x$data[[i]]$text)+1] <- c("")
}
fixed
```

How could I add a legend tooltip. For instance, for 1 I would like to show "Cat", for two I would like to show "Dog"...and so on.

Thanks

Comment: These names would be based on the V1 column from 1 to 6?

Comment: On the V2 column from 1 to 40.

Comment: So will it be 40 different names?

Comment: It sounds like you just want to rename the levels of your factor so there are different labels.

Comment: This examlpe is very simplyfied. Actually, in my real legend, I have for instance the following variable with factors: E, NE, EPT, EPTIS which is not comprehensive for people who don't know what mean each factor. So in order to be more clear, I would like to add a pop-up on the legend: E = employed, NE = unemployed, EPT = employed with part time job, EPTIS = employed with part time job in the industrial sector.....If it was easy to label, I would do as you said Jake.

Comment: @Mily I think I have a similar question. Did you get any answer or find a workaround?